# Merging and rotation of document with different page format and size

Tags: c#, itext

## Context :

I currently have multiple PDF files. Few of them are generated by crystal report as portrait and landscape format. These cover about 5 to 20 pdf with 1 or 2 pages each. The rest is between 60 to 100 pdf from multiple different companies with 1 to 10 pages each.

## Goals :

1 - Merge all these PDF

2 - Force portrait or landscape on all pages

## What i've achieved :

Merging PDF was really simple, using `PdfCopy` in conjunction with `pdfWriter.GetImportedPage()` did the trick. So goal #1 is complete.

## Problems :

I am having problem when the file i merge have multiple different layout. Let me clarify. I have a file named `a.pdf` and this file has 3 pages. Page 1 is portrait 8.5x11 while page 2 and 3 are landscape 17x11. I need the document if i request portrait to be :

- page 1 portrait 8.5x11
- page 2 portrait 11x17
- page 3 portrait 11x17

in other word, page 2 and 3 need a rotation and we want 90 degree counter clock wise for design reasons.

When merging files with different page format my merging code now generate the file but the file is 0kb. So different format doesn't generate properly.

So i made my rotation method but again this result in 0kb files. The problem with rotation and itextsharp i only found that i can use the `Document` object which have only ONE page size property for the whole document instead of per page and i believe that is my problem in both case.

I have been working on finding solution for the past 5 hours online but all solutions still use the `Document` object and it set page size to the size of the first page of the PDF document.

I might be missing something, i haven't worked with `itextsharp` in 2 years so i'm quite rusty.

## Code :

This is my merging pdf method :

```
public static bool MergeFiles(List<string> filePathToMerge, string filePathToOutput)
{
    var success = false;

    try
    {
        var validFiles = filePathToMerge.Where(f => File.Exists(f)).ToList();

        if (validFiles.Count > 0)
        {
            // merge the files with pdf
            var pdfDocument = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
            var pdfWriter = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy(pdfDocument, new FileStream(filePathToOutput, FileMode.Create));
            pdfDocument.Open();

            validFiles.ForEach(f =>
            {
                var pdfReader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(f);
                pdfReader.ConsolidateNamedDestinations();

                for (int pageNo = 1; pageNo <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; pageNo++)
                {
                    var pageImported = pdfWriter.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, pageNo);
                    pdfWriter.AddPage(pageImported);
                }

                pdfReader.Close();
            });

            pdfWriter.Close();
            pdfDocument.Close();

            success = true;
        }
    }
    catch { }

    return success;
}
```

This is my rotation method

```
public static bool ChangeOrientation(string filePath, string filePathOutput, bool portrait)
{
    var success = false;

    try
    {
        // check if we will replace the file
        var replaceFile = filePath == filePathOutput;

        // make sure the file exists
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            // teh pdf reader
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filePath);

            // an empty document
            var document = new Document();

            // the pdf writer
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(filePathOutput + (replaceFile ? "2" : ""), FileMode.Create));

            // open the document
            document.Open();

            // get content byte
            var cb = writer.DirectContent;

            // get page quantity
            var pageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;

            // for each page we will check if rotation required otherwise we simply copy the page to the new document
            for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
            {
                // create new page with size
                document.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i));
                document.NewPage();

                // get page dimensions
                var pageSize = reader.GetPageSize(i);

                // check if rotation is required
                var isRotationRequired = (pageSize.Width > pageSize.Height && portrait) || (pageSize.Width < pageSize.Height && !portrait);

                // get the page imported
                var importedPage = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);

                // if rotation required apply i to the imported page
                if (isRotationRequired)
                {
                    // if rotation required an we request portrait, it means the page is landscape once it reach this part of code.
                    // we then want the landscape page to rotate 90 degree counter clockwise so the bottom of the page is on the right.
                    // If we want lanscape and the page is portrait and we want want the bottom of the page to be on the right so we also
                    // want a 90 degree counter clockwise rotation

                    // here i take the current rotation minus our arbitrary 90 degree we wanted, like so if it has
                    // any rotations already i dont care what it is since i already know from the dimensions it's not properly rotated
                    // all page i will feed to this method will only contain right angle rotations
                    var rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(i) - 90;

                    // add rotated page
                    cb.AddTemplate(importedPage, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Width, 0);

                }
                else
                {
                    cb.AddTemplate(importedPage, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
                }                        
            }

            // close the reader
            reader.Close();

            // close writer
            writer.Close();

            // close document
            document.Close();

            if (replaceFile)
            {
                // delete old file
                File.Delete(filePath);

                // rename the file
                File.Move(filePath + "2", filePath);
            }

            success = true;
         }
    }
    catch { }

    return success;
}
```

Comment: The "method" you are using to rotate pages is destructive and wrong. Please consult the official documentation, for instance [How to rotate a page 90 degrees?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-rotate-page-90-degrees) You check the page size and rotation at the `PdfReader` level; you change the page size and rotation at the `PdfReader` level. Searching the official documentation for [page rotation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/tags/page-rotation) takes less than 5 minutes, not 5 hours.

Comment: unfortunately that was my first test and it does not work with all PDF, i works only on 1 of 3 test pdf. One return as 0kb with a `PdfReader not opened with owner password` error, the other simply do not rotate properly.

Comment: Rotation seems to be working with latest dll version. we use to have version 3.1.0 i think. but some document we created still have the error `PdfReader not opened with owner password` the error happen when using the `pdfStamper` object. is there a way around that object and use something else to save ?

Comment: All versions prior to 5 have been discontinued many years ago. Version 3.1.0 dates from 2004. If you are really using a version that old, your question can't be taken seriously. I won't do any effort on this question, because that would be a complete waste of my time.

Comment: Also: you are trying to open encrypted PDFs (hence the reference to a password). If it's only encrypted with an owner password, iText can open it, if you set a special parameter. If it's also encrypted using a user password, you have to provide that password.